# iframe to fill page, without javascript

Tags: css, iframe

I have a page with an iframe, it is rendered to be letter box shaped. I am trying to get it to fill the page vertically. Horizontal size seems to be no problem (60% with sidebars left and right).

I have got it to work in chrome, but not firefox. It needs to work everywhere (modern). I also want to avoid javascript.

css — working on chrome, and not firefox (I read somewhere that this should not work (according to standards), but why?:

```
iframe, .menu, .main{
   height: 100%;
}
```

css — kludge: not independent of screen size

```
iframe, .menu, .main{
   height: 100em;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/s.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1></h1>      
    </header>

    <div class="group">

      <div class="menu">
        <iframe src="menu">
          Your user agent does not support frames or is currently configured not to display frames. However, you may visit
          <a href="menu">the index here</a>
        </iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        <iframe src="main">
          Your user agent does not support frames or is currently configured not to display frames. However, you may visit
          <a href="main">the content here</a>
        </iframe>   
      </div>

      <aside>
        <p>hello side</p>
      </aside>

    </div>

    <footer>
      <p>hello footer</p>      
    </footer>
  </body> 
</html>
```

css

```
/*background colour*/

header,
.menu,
.main,
section,
aside,
footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #888; 
}

/*layout*/

footer {
    clear: both;
}

header,
footer {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


.menu,
.main,
section
aside
footer {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body,
.group {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

iframe {
    width : 100%;
    border: 0;
}

iframe, .menu, .main {
   height: 100%; 
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}

/*default*/
/*side at bottom on non wide screen*/
aside {
    clear: both; 
}

/*if wide enough put menu on left side*/
@media all and (min-width: 1040px) {
    .menu {
        width: 24.9%;
        float: left; 
    }

    .main,
    section {
        width: 75%; 
        float: left; 
    }
}

/*wide screen — all side by side*/
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {

    .menu {
        width: 17%;
    float: left
    }

    .main,
    section {
        width: 64%;
    float: left;
    }

    aside {
        width: 17%;
        clear: none;
        float: right; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow...uh yeah: don't put an `iframe` element inside of a `nav` element; also there is no such thing as a `menu` element. Whatever tutorials you are reading...stop. Use Mozilla Developer Network, here is a good starting place for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element Also you have zero reasons to use `iframe` elements for navigation, that will probably sink you in Google serps.

Comment: @john can you explain (I get the bit about menu, so I removed menu tag, in case it is not yet implemented: mozila web site says it is experimental)

Comment: So apparently the WHATWG can't make up their minds with the `menu` element and everyone was supposed to use the `nav` element so until *they* make up their minds just stick to the `nav` element. The `iframe` element is something you want to use as sparingly as possible and I outright reject them (we're now past the need for frames in general and I advocated for them during the lack of tech needed to properly replace them). You'll need to learn how to splice your data on the server so you can reuse it properly; I'm guessing you're not well versed in server side languages such as PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally css now allows this. With use of `vh` (viewport height): see also `vw`, `vmax`, `vmin`.

See example below, it also uses the new css grid. css flex should also work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iframe-layout-exp.css"/>
  </head>
  <body class="wrapper">
    <header class="box">Header — this is a header</header>

    <main>
      <iframe src="http://bookmarkdb/">
    What no iframes.
      </iframe>
      </main>
    <nav class="box">
      Menubar — This is a menu bar
    </nav>
    <aside class="box">Sidebar  — this is a sidebar</aside>

    <footer class="box">Footer — this is the footer</footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Note the simple html; no extra divs; It just describes the semantics of the page, all elements are in a sane order.

```
/*******************************/
/*Layout*/

nav      {grid-area: sidebar; }
aside    {grid-area: sidebar2;}
main     {grid-area: content;}
header   {grid-area: header;}
footer   {grid-area: footer;}

html, body, .wrapper, main{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 120px auto 120px;
    grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header  header header"
        "sidebar content sidebar2"
        "sidebar footer footer";
}

main {
    display:grid;
}

/*******************************/
/*style*/

.box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: #999;
}

nav, aside {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

And the css.